# Windows to Linux Ping not working while Telnet works

Tags: linux, windows, ping, telnet

On Linux we have a service running which is listening on port 9999 but when we try to check it from a Windows machine on same network with PING it says :

> Ping request could not find host 10.32.9.82:9999

while when I tried using telnet like

```
telnet 10.32.9.82 9999
```

and Telnet got connected successfully.

So what I am trying to understand that why the telnet worked but does PING not as the service is listening on the IP and port on TCP.

Comment: Ping uses ICMP, which does not have the concept of ports. Telnet uses TCP, which uses ports as addressing. You cannot ping to a port number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't ping a port number (ping says that the device is reachable, nothing more).

But you can use something like this powershell cmdlet instead: [Test-NetConnection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/test-netconnection)

```perl
Test-NetConnection 10.32.9.82 -Port 9999
```

You'll get an output like that, note that the output shows if Ping succeeded, and if the port is reachable, that's two different things !

```
RemoteAddress          : 10.32.9.82
RemotePort             : 9999
InterfaceAlias         : Ethernet
SourceAddress          : 192.168.1.166
PingSucceeded          : True
PingReplyDetails (RTT) : 1 ms
TcpTestSucceeded       : True
```

Comment: thanks, makes sense now, is telnet and this command are same thing ?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad No, telnet is an old protocol to connect to a terminal and send/receive text commands. Telnet is not meant to check if ports are open, although some people use it for that but it makes little sense.
Something like `Test-NetConnection` is meant to Test network connections so it's the command I recommend for this use case. Plus it's easily scriptable.